# How to zoom in and out using bluetooth mouse?

Tags: bluetooth, mouse, zooming

We zoom in and out using two fingers in an android app such as PDF viewer or map. If I use a bluetooth mouse, how can I do this?
The wheel does not seem to work for this purpose.

Comment: Would love to hear if it worked for you, if it did, you can accept the answer by pressing on the check mark below, otherwise let be know if it didn't work. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In many apps, if you click with the left button once and then click again and hold it down, you should be able to zoom in and out while dragging the mouse up and down.